# MongoDB Java Document.get() from keyValues holding comma seperated integers

Tags: java, mongodb

Imagine a Document, named `doc`, that looks something like this:

> ```
>    "_id" : ObjectId("56896bbf713dffe8799e0970"),
>    "Section Name" : "BUS-110-01",
>    "Title" : "Business & Entrep. Mindset",,
>    "Building" : "CCM",
>    "Room" : 442, 443,
>    "Days" : "T, TH",
>    "Start Time" : "12:30 PM",
>    "End time" : "1:45 PM",
> ```

When I run `String myRoom = doc.getString("Room")` I get an exception. I tried `doc.getInteger("Room")` and `doc.getDouble("Room")` and had no success, not that I expected much.

If I create an `ArrayList<String> Room` and run:

`Room.add(doc.get("Room", String.class))` I get `java.lang.ClassCastException: Cannot cast java.lang.Integer to java.lang.String`

Ironically if I create an `ArrayList<Integer> Room` and run:

`Room.add(doc.get("Room", Integer.class))` I get `java.lang.ClassCastException: Cannot cast java.lang.String to java.lang.Integer`

As if "Room" has some sort of identity crisis.

Any hints on what I might be missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Should of gone one step furhter. `ArrayList<Object> myList` and `myList.add(doc.get("Room", Object.class))` solved the issue.